# How to change the font size depending to the sreen size Vue js 3/ Quasar2?

Tags: vue.js, class, if-statement, vuex, quasar

I'm expecting to change font classes when changing the screen width with vue js3/quasar2. But it fails, I seem to do everything correct. I do it with options API.

```js
// quasar.config.js 
framework: {
  config: {
    screen: {
      bodyClasses: true
    }
  },
}

// component
<template>
  <p :class="fontSize">text content</p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        $q: useQuasar()
      }
    },
    computed: {
      fontSize() {
        if(this.$q.screen.lt.sm) {
          return 'text-body1'
        } else {
          return 'text-body2'              // I always get this line class while resizing the screen
        }
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's maybe some confusion over the difference between Vue's [Options API](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#options-api) and [Composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#what-is-composition-api), because your code is a mix of both, when you should always stick with one.  Your code is mainly using Options API but then the line
`$q: useQuasar()` is attempting to use a [composable](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) which is specific to the Composition API.

When using "the $q object", the [Quasar documentation](https://quasar.dev/options/the-q-object) has clear examples on how to use it with every API style and use case.  With the Options API, there's nothing you need to do other than use `this.$q` wherever needed.  It is automatically provided for you by Quasar as a global object. Your attempt to define `$q` yourself within `data()` is what broke it for you.

This is all your component's script needs to be:

```js
<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      fontSize() {
        if(this.$q.screen.lt.sm) {
          return 'text-body1'
        } else {
          return 'text-body2'
        }
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```